# SQL create view with connecting flight

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following Task:

I need to create a view that shows the 1st Flight and his connecting flight.

In this example FlightNo 1&2.

-

My Flight table:

```
FlightNo---Date--------StartTime---ArrivingTime---StartPort---DestinationPort

 1. ----2014-11-20---01:00:55-----02:00:34----------a----------------b
 2. ----2014-11-20---02:10:55-----03:00:34----------b----------------c
 3. ----2014-11-20---20:00:55-----21:00:34----------x----------------q
 4. ----2014-11-20---00:00:55-----01:00:34----------a----------------u
```

…

My Code so far:

```
create OR REPLACE view FlightConnection as

select* FROM Flight a

where  exists  (select* FROM Flight b
where a.StartPort = b.DestinationPort and
a.ArrivingTime < b.StartTimet);
```

My Output:

```
FlightNo---Date--------StartTime---ArrivingTime---StartPort---DestinationPort

 ---1 ----2014-11-20---01:00:55-----02:00:34----------a----------------b
```

-

But I need FlightNo 1 and 2.
I tried several different thing but I think I’m momentarily to dumb.

Please Help.
(sorry for my english)

Comment: So you want pairs of flights such that the destination port of the first is the start port of the second, and the arrival time of the first is before the departure time of the second?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a (self-)`JOIN` to get result rows that contain data about both flights of a possible connection.  This should get you started:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW FlightConnection AS
  SELECT *
  FROM Flight a
    JOIN Flight b
      ON a.DestinationPort = b.StartPort
        AND a.Date = b.Date
        AND a.ArrivingTime < b.StartTime
```

Comment: You will probably want to select specific columns and assign aliases to them, instead of just selecting `*`.

Comment: yes, somthing isn'T working now mysql is crying about error 1060 duplicate column name FlightNo

Comment: Either select specific columns in the select list and assign distinct aliases to them, or put an appropriate column list before the `AS`.  Or both.